# jQuery - selecting a drop down value that will remove a value from another drop down

Tags: jquery

I'm new to jquery and I am having trouble with this problem that I am working through. I have drop_down_list1 that has 6 values. Should the user select value 1 or 2, a value from drop_down_list2 will be removed. Should the user select the value 3, 4, 5, or 6 from drop_down_list1 than only value 5 from drop_down_list2 can be selected.

I am being told that my logic is right there but the syntax is off. Can any one please assist me? Thank you!

```
$(function () {

        $("#drop_down_list1").change(function (){
            var select = $("#drop_down_list1").val();  
            if (select == '1', '2') {          
                $("#drop_down_list2").find("option[value='5']").remove();
            }
            else if (select == '3', '4', '5', '6') {
                $("drop_down_list2").find("option[value='1','2','3','4',]").remove();
            }
            else {
                $("#drop_down_list2").find("option[value='5']").append();
            }
        })
    });
```

Comment: select == '1', '2' should be select == '1'||select=='2'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two corrections.

#### 1.edit your conditions

There is syntax error in your if conditions

```
if (select == '1', '2')
```

should be

```
if (select == '1' || select == '2')
```

#### 2.edit your find selector with multiple conditions

Below Jquery selector with multiple conditions in find will not work

```
 $("drop_down_list2").find("option[value='1','2','3','4']").remove();
```

may be you could try

```
 $("drop_down_list2").find("option[value!='5']").remove();
```

which would be the same effect

#### update

for selecting multiple options in find you may also use

```
$("drop_down_list2").find("option[value='1'], option[value='2'], option[value='3'], option[value='4']").remove();
```